# Why does this if statement return the value true?

Tags: java, if-statement, integer

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    if(year < 1 || year > 9999) {
        return false;
    }else {
        if(year % 4 == 0) {
            return true;
        }if(year % 100 != 0 && year % 400 == 0) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The integer (year) is 9000, it should have returned false but got true instead. What went wrong?

Comment: You return true if `(year % 4 == 0)` check your logic again

Comment: It's a multiple of 4.

Comment: 9000 / 4 = 2250 with no remainder.  Check it with a calculator.

Comment: Remember that computers do exactly what you tell them to do, not what you want them to do.

Answer (score 0):

The anser is on line 5:

```
year % 4 == 0
```

This evaluates to true because 9000 is divisible by 4.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the year%4 evaluates to 0 for year=9000. 
Here's the logic for computing a leap year

```
bool isLeap = false;
if (year % 4 == 0) {
    if (year % 100 == 0) {
        if (year % 400 == 0) {
            isLeap = true;
        }
        else {
            isLeap = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        isLeap = true;
    }
}
else {
    isLeap = false;
}
return isLeap
```